# Best way to convert date to epoch in perl

Tags: perl, date, time, epoch

What is the best way to convert --> Mar 11 10:29:47 2021 GMT <-- into epoch on **multiple platforms**.
Date::Parse module is not available by default on all platforms.

Comment: Regular expressions can only help you in matching all or parts of a date string from a context, but you'd still have to implement the logic to convert what you matched into a UNIX timestamp. Quite a number of languages have some form of date string to date object/timestamp functionality; you'll have to use that specifically for each scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `strptime()` ("string parse time") method from [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) which has been a part of the standard Perl distribution since 5.10.0 in 2007.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece;

my $str = 'Mar 11 10:29:47 2021 GMT';
my $fmt = '%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z';

my $date = Time::Piece->strptime($str, $fmt);

say $date->epoch; # prints 1615458587
```

`strptime` is a standard Unix tool which is available in many forms. You can get more information about the format strings that it uses from its [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime).